# JGit sparse checkout keeps adding files

Tags: java, git, jgit

In Java, I'm working with [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) for performing some actions with a remote repository. However when I sequentially do a sparse checkout between versions with:

```java
checkout.
  setCreateBranch(false).
  setName(tag).
  addPath("server/scripts/").
  setStartPoint(tag);
```

It keeps the last checkout file and adds new one. It only happens when the name of the files inside the directory are not the same. How could I avoid that when using checkout command this way?

I thought about deleting files inside folder that is being checkout (*scripts*, in this case), however I don't know if it will bring conflict when the file being *'downloaded'* has the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that `setCreateBranch()` is false by default, hence there is no need to explicitly call `setCreateBranch( false )`.

Furthermore, you cannot mix `addPath()` and `setName()` The JavaDoc for `addPath()` says:

> If this option is set, neither the setCreateBranch(boolean) nor setName(String) option is considered. In other words, these options are exclusive.

However, I am not sure if the behavior that you see is correct. In doubt check with command-line git to see if it shows the same results and [file a bug report](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/) if JGit differs.

To work around the orphan files, you can use the `StatusCommand` to manually delete all untracked files:

```
Status status = git.status().call();
for( String fileName : status.getUntracked() ) {
  // delete fileName
}
```